# concatenate strings in SAS

Tags: sas

used || to concatenate two strings and overwrite one of the variable. But overwrite does not happen sometime.

Here is my 1st code:

```
data aa;
length a b $3;
a = 'FA';
b = '1';
a = a || b;
run;
```

Value of a is still 'FA'.
But if we replace the concatenate with:
`$` b = a || b;
then b will have the value 'FA1'.

Can anyone explain why this happens

Comment: `||` is an OR operator is most languages. In this case since the first value is truth, it will return it. Not sure what's the proper operator to concatenate in SAS

Comment: See this link: https://amadeus.co.uk/tips/concatenating-strings/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS character variables store the trailing spaces of a value to fill the variable length. Values combined with the concatenation operator `||` are not modified in any way, thus the effective operation (value-wise) with the variables is:

```
a = "FA " || "1  "
```

So `FA<space>1<space><space>` is getting stuffed into $3 and truncating to `FA<space>`

Old school code would be

```
a = trim(left(a))||left(b);
```

Review the `CAT*` family of functions for concatenating values with trimming, stripping and delimiting.  For example:

```
a = cats(a,b);
```